# Password policy not applying to DCs

Tags: group-policy

I have created a Group Policy object (GPO) at the domain level w/password settings. It's security is such that it applies to all domain computers and domain controllers.

The problem is that when I run a resultant check, it shows the GPO being applied, but on two of my 3 DCs, under the settings, there is no password policy. I have zero GP errors showing.

It just is not applying to two of my DCs. The GPO is at the domain level. Driving me crazy.

Comment: The DC it does work on is the one with the DC Emulator role

Comment: Is the password policy a User or Computer policy?

Comment: It is a computer policy. I think I may be on to something. I checked the local security policy on the DCs where the password settings were not applying, and the settings were there. So it led down a path and I found another article saying that it is be design....that the settings will only show on the server w/the PDC role. To test, I changed the password policy, did a gp update, and the settings were updated on the DC where they are not showing. Wondering if anyone can confirm this?